# Implement Swipe Gesture on a RecyclerView Item?

Tags: android, swipe, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I have seen nice solutions to implement onClick and onLongClick gesture in OnItemTouchListener.
What I am looking for now is the code to implement a Swipe Gesture in OnItemTouchListener.

If you have any idea or if you came across a blog or a tutorial , please let me know.Thanks.

Comment: Swipe Recycler View 
https://github.com/rahulrj/Swipe_RecyclerView

Comment: Thanks Diffy, though I just wanted to capture the swipe gestion without make an actual swipe movement, I will take a look at the code of this library and try to copy/past some code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34740985/5710872